# Bash Function that checks if there is text in a file and adds the text if it is not

Tags: bash

Please note that this question was answered fully in my follow up question here: [I keep on getting host=dynamic when inputting the filepath into bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888260/i-keep-on-getting-host-dynamic-when-inputting-the-filepath-into-bash-function?noredirect=1#comment107731158_60888260)

2018: Intermediate Pneumatics Training at Hytec Holdings

I am trying to create a function that will check if a file in contains text.

If the file already contains this text, the function should add the text to the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Function that checks if text (ARGV1) is in a document (ARGV2). Please make ARGV1 a an array of strings, with each new line a new entry in the array.
function docCheckNReplace {
    local text=$1
    local document=$2
    local textLen=${#text[@]}
    for i in {0..$(($textLen - 1))..1}; do
        echo $i
        if grep -q ${test[i]} $document; then
            echo ${test[i]} 'was found in' $document
        else
            echo ${test[i]} >> $document
        fi
    done
}
```

This is what I've come up with so far.

Linux freezes when I run it so I can't figure out where the problem is.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Comment: Errr, you haven't actually called it anywhere AFAIK.

Comment: One of the mistakes is that you're confusing `text` and `test`. Your Linux didn't freeze, instead, `grep` is waiting for input on `stdin`. Also think about how to split the first argument on line breaks and put the lines into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the output of `echo "$i"` instead of `echo $i`.

What do you think should be the output of `{0..5..1}`?

You can not use variables in the range operator. Use `seq` instead.

And array indexing works this way: `${test[$i]}`.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe that I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

We need not bother with array indexing; we can simply process the text line by line:

```
    while read i; do
        echo $i
        if grep -q "$i" $document; then
            echo "$i" 'was found in' $document
        else
            echo "$i" >> $document
        fi
    done <<<$1
```