# I keep on getting host=dynamic when inputting the filepath into bash function

Tags: linux, bash

This is follow up question to [Bash Function that checks if there is text in a file and adds the text if it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60881858/bash-function-that-checks-if-there-is-text-in-a-file-and-adds-the-text-if-it-is/60884407#60884407)

I am trying to create a bash function that will check if a file has text in it. If the text is in the file do not text. If it is add the text. My code is

```
#!/bin/bash
#Function that checks if text (ARGV1) is in a document (ARGV2). Please make ARGV1 an array of strings, with each new line a new entry in the array.

declare -a inputText=("[test]" "host=dynamic" "disallow=all" "allow=alaw" "allow=ulaw" "type=friend" "context=test" "secret=test")

function docCheckNReplace {
    local text=$1
    local document=$2
    echo $document
    local textLen=${#text[@]}
    for ((i=0; i<textLen; i++)); do
        if grep -q "${text[$i]}" $document; then
            echo 'found'
            echo ${test[$i]} 'was found in' $document
        else
            echo 'not found'
            echo ${test[$i]} >> $document
        fi
    done
}
docCheckNReplace ${inputText[@]} /home/kam/Documents/TextingSed.txt
```

Now, whenever I echo out the input filepath argument it returns "host=dynamic".

When I set the first argument to inputText and not ${inputText[@]} it works fine.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Also change argument order. Document as argument 1 and text as vararg 2...

Comment: You can't pass an array as an argument; using `"${inputText[@]}"` as an argument passes *the elements* of the array as arguments, with *each one as a separate argument*. That's why you put them at the end, because you don't necessarily know how many there are. Oh, and if you pass the array's contents without putting double-quotes around it, the shell will try to parse each element in irrelevant and potentially disastrous ways before passing it. *Always* double-quote your variable references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing search strings as first argument, pass it as a vararg for argument 2 and above. Variable number of arguments has to be last regardless of the programming language.

String literals are written in single-quote for efficiently avoiding parsing for potential variable/sub-shell expansions syntax.

Adds double quotes around variables.

Uses `printf` rather than `echo` when formatting strings with mixed literals and variables.

Uses the `-F` option with `grep` to search for plain text rather than interpreting the search string as a Regex.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Function that checks if texts (vararg ARGV2) is in a document (ARGV1).
#Please make ARGV2 an array of strings, with each new line a new entry in the array.

declare -a inputText=('[test]' 'host=dynamic' 'disallow=all' 'allow=alaw' 'allow=ulaw' 'type=friend' 'context=test' 'secret=test')

function docCheckNReplace {
    local document="$1"
    # Shift out document from arguments array
    # Now it only contains vararg search strings
    shift

    echo "$document"
    for search_string; do
        if grep -qF "$search_string" "$document"; then
            echo 'found'
            printf '%s was found in %s.\n' "$search_string" "$document"
        else
            echo 'not found'
            echo "$search_string" >> "$document"
        fi
    done
}

docCheckNReplace '/home/kam/Documents/TextingSed.txt' "${inputText[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. I just don't understand where the search_string variable came from. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @KamKam `search_string` is iterating the arguments. `for search_string; do` is an abbreviated syntax of `for search_string in "$@"; do`. When iterating the arguments, the argument array mention can be omitted because it is implicit.